# Javascript jQuery - selecting select box option only works sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-select

the project is an MVC project writen in PHP

I have an AJAX call in a veiw that echoes, into a div, a bit of Javascript that does some things on the page. At the end of the script is a piece of JQuery that should change a select boxes selected option. I did plenty of research into switching select options on this website and others, and after some playing around i got this bit of code to work:

```
function filterSet(optValue){

    $("#mySelect option").prop('selected', false)
                         .filter('[value="'+ optValue +'"]')
                         .prop('selected', true);
}
```

The strange thing is, that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt. Testing it over the last hour or so, it hasent worked once, but it did work before that, and the only change to the code that i made is a change of the enclosing method name.

the error the console is giving is 'ReferenceError: maple is not defined' where 'maple' is the word in the optValue variable.

ReferenceError: maple is not defined

i dont understand why i would get an undefined error considering the value of the select option is hardcoded into the select html, and ive tried the jquery with hardcoding the option value to what the variable is suppose to pass in, but i still get the same error, this is strange because there once was a time when this code worked perfectly! more than once actually, it worked when testing it several times! but know its not.

select box html:

```
<select id="mySelect">
        <option value = 'all' selected> Ward </option>
        <option value = 'maple'> Maple </option>
        <option value = 'oak'> Oak </option>
        <option value = 'w3'> Ward 3 </option>
        <option value = 'w4'> Ward 4 </option>
        <option value = 'w5'> Ward 5 </option>
        <option value = 'w6'> Ward 6 </option>
</select>
```

can anyone shed some light on this?

how the filterSet method is called. An ajax call causes this script to be echoed into a div on the page, on the success callback of the ajax call filterSet() is called.

```
echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function locateSpecific(){

            scale = 1;
            height =' . $height . '
            width =' . $width . '

            var imageUrl = "' . $imageURL . '";
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds([0, 0], [height / scale,width / scale]);

            map.removeLayer(markerGroup);

            L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, bounds, { noWrap: true, maxZoom: 3, minZoom: -3 }).addTo(map);

            }

            filterSet('.$loc.');

            </script>

            ';
```

Comment: The error message suggests that, somewhere, you're using a variable of the name `maple `, rather than a string. You've not shown how you call your function though, so we can't really help unfortunately.

Comment: Please show how you are using this. Code shown won't produce that error by itself

Comment: thanks David, sould the quotes around the variable not sort this out? as in there is the double quotes surrounding then variable, this should make the variable value into a string no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the PHP code. You aren't quoting the string that you are passing to the function, so it thinks that it's a reference.

**Solution:**

Here is the erroneous line:

```
filterSet('.$loc.');
```

You need to make sure to output quotes around it:

```
filterSet("'.$loc.'");
```

**Explanation:**

When `$loc` is set to the string `"maple"` it will output the following string to the web browser.

```
filterSet(maple);
```

The javascript interpreter will then try to find the variable `maple` instead of using the string `"maple"`. It will then throw a reference error because it can't find it.

With the updated code the PHP will instead send the following.

```
filterSet("maple");
```

Since this is a string it will now work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Use a function as argument for the filter method :

```js
function filterSet(optValue){
    $("#mySelect option")
        .filter(function () { return $(this).val() == optValue; })
 .prop('selected',true)
}

filterSet('oak');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
        <option value = 'all' selected> Ward </option>
        <option value = 'maple'> Maple </option>
        <option value = 'oak'> Oak </option>
        <option value = 'w3'> Ward 3 </option>
        <option value = 'w4'> Ward 4 </option>
        <option value = 'w5'> Ward 5 </option>
        <option value = 'w6'> Ward 6 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: why do you even need a filter on options just to set value on a select?

Comment: Ah, right, `$("#mySelect").val('oak')` works as well. Sometimes you don't see the obvious :) But the filter works too!

Comment: thanks, doesnt seem to work for me, still getting the reference error, maple not defined. im wondering is the error in relation to the optValue variable, or is it saying that the actual value of the html select option is not defined?

Comment: This will do the exact same thing, and it has nothing to do with the `ReferenceError` that was thrown.